# How to send File from webview to javascript in android

Tags: javascript, android

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {

        @JavascriptInterface
        public File onGetPic() {
            return file;
        }
    }, "getPicture");
```

When I send a File to javascript, js cannot read the File.Like this:

```
function getPic(){
        var file = window.getPicture.onGetPic();
        alert(file);
        alert(file.length);
    }
```

This will alert Object and Undefined.
What should I do to solve the problem.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an object property within the "file" object.

1) try alert(file.length())
2) console.log your "file" object and inspect its properties

Comment: I tried this.It doesn't work.Returns always "Undefined".